# can't import npm package using ember-browserify (Uncaught Error: Could not find module)

Tags: ember.js, npm

In my ember application I have installed ember-browserify by running

`npm install ember-browserify --save`

I have then installed pit-scheduler by running

`npm install pit-scheduler --save`

and then I have restarted ember but when I go to the page I get this error

> Uncaught Error: Could not find module npm:pit-scheduler imported from my-app/routes/schedule

Is it because I need to also npm install all of the dependency packages somehow? 
in the actual package example these are packages which are being imported

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/pitscheduler.min.js"></script>
```

I have already installed these packages by running npm install as well but still the same issue. Any idea why that is the case?

url to the packages

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pit-scheduler
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browserify
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that pit-schedular can't be included that way to Ember. Here's what you could do, clone pit-scheduler repository in vendor folder and then import it to ember-cli-build.js from there with:

```
app.import('vendor/pit-scheduler/dist/js/pitscheduler.min.js');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow :)